# How do you localize the {verb} + {noun} pattern?

Tags: guidelines, copywriting, localization

By example, if we take **[Resend confirmation email]**, how would you localize that for Germany?

**[Bestätigungsmail erneut senden]** (noun + verb)?

Are there design guidelines available online?

Comment: Just don't translate verb and noun seperately and leave the exact translation to a translator. You will need translations anyway, so my advice is not to mess with it programmatically.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to provide some sort of guidelines to the translator as well, though?

Comment: "Resend confirmation email" is a complete (imperative) English sentence. You may want to give translators advice on level of formality, length, etc., but it is not unreasonable to expect them to translate whole sentences into whole sentences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to localize or translate your user interface and its terminology, you really should look what the big ones are doing. Microsoft has a great tool for searching localized user interface terminology used in their own products. Probably called [Language Portal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language) (their UI isn't the best).

It doesn't seem to have your phrase specifically but similar ones.

For example `Resend verification email` is `Bestätigungs-E-Mail erneut senden` in Exchange Server or `Überprüfungs-E-Mail erneut senden` in Office 365.

(Why haven't Microsoft used same translations in different products or user interfaces is another question though.)

Answer (score 0):

verb + noun just does not work in e.g. german. The structure of the language does not allow it.

For localization you should use the structure given by the language. In german it usually it is noun + verb (which is a little more to read or process, but the users are used to this).

If you would have the verb in front, you would have to use a whole sentence which would make the CTA even less readable something like «Senden des Bestätiguns-E-Mails wiederholen». So as you mentioned in german it usually is noun + verb (I cant think of an exception (which does not mean that there are none)).

Comment: "*Senden wiederholen*" still has the verb (wiederholen) in the end.